# freebsd shell package not execute after successfull install

Tags: freebsd

After successfull installing midnight commander with pkg_add - mc i try to load it from shell command "mc", but it did not work. Leaving the root and going root again fixes that problem. The same thing with the other packages. Is there a kind of refresh util or something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the `rehash` command, your shell is most likely keeping a cache of executables within your `PATH`.

Comment: this works fine

Answer (score 0):

Command `rehash` works with (t)csh shell, with bash you can use `hash -r`.